# Continuous $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$. Does $f(X)$ contain a decreasing and converging sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis

This is an exploratory question. $f$ is a continuous real function on space $X$. $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$.

> Does there exist an infinite sequence $$f(x_1)>f(x_2)>f(x_3)>\dots>f(x_n)>\dots$$
> converging to a real number?

I think the answer is yes. By the definition of continuous function we can always find some infinite sequence out. But I don't know how to find decreasing sequences.

If my claim is false, then what is the topological assumptions on $X$ for the claim to be true? (I think Martin makes a great point that the claim is true when $X$ is a real interval.)

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: @paw88789 I guess the answer is yes because continuity implies the existence of many converging sequence.

Comment: The intermediate value theorem is your friend!

Comment: @MartinR Many thanks! this make the question much easier. Does intermediate value theorem works only with real function with real variable, or does it work with real function with any kind of variables?

Comment: The intermediate value theorem is about continuous functions mapping a real interval to $\Bbb R$. It does not hold for functions of several variables, but there are some kind of generalizations. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Generalizations

Comment: @AnneBauval sequence $f$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $x_1 = 1$ and then use the  intermediate value theorem repeatedly:

- $f(0) = 0$, $f(x_1) = 1$ implies that there is a $x_2 \in (0, x_1)$ with $f(x_2) = 1/2$.
- $f(0) = 0$, $f(x_2) = 1/2$ implies that there is a $x_3 \in (0, x_2)$ with $f(x_3) = 1/3$.
- ...

This gives a strictly decreasing sequence $(x_n)$ with $f(x_n) = 1/n$.

Re your edit: If $X$ is a connected topological space and $f: X \to \Bbb R$ is continuous with $f(a) = 0$, $f(b) = 1$ then one can define the sequence $(x_n)$ recursively in the same way (compare [Intermediate value theorem: General metric and topological spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#General_metric_and_topological_spaces)).

- $x_1 = b$.
- If $x_n \in X$ has been defined with $f(x_n) =1/n$ then $f(a) = 0$, $f(x_n) = 1/n$ implies that there is a $x_{n+1} \in X$ with $f(x_{n-1}) = 1/(n+1)$.

Again $(f(x_n))$ is striclty decreasing and bounded below (therefore convergent), but we do not have an ordering between the $(x_n)$ now.

Comment: I think the $x_n$ is Decreasing too. In other words , we have $f(x_n)$ Increasing with Increasing $x_n$ : I am not sure whether this is what OP wants. In case , this is what OP wants , then it is almost obvious. Maybe , I am missing Something.

Comment: After some research, the IVT applied to any connected topological space, which solve most of the problem https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intermediate_Value_Theorem_(Topology) Am I correct?

Comment: @dodo: Yes, that is correct, the IVT is valid in that situation. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $X$ is connected. Then by the intermediate value theorem so is $f(X),$ which therefore contains $[f(x),f(y)]=[0,1]$ and a fortiori contains many strictly decreasing and converging sequences $(f(x_n)).$

Comment: Yes, that is a simpler answer to the updated question.